# failed to find constructor for type MvxViewModelLoader MvvmCross IOS

Tags: ios, constructor, mvvmcross

I use MvvmCross for develop a CrossPlatform App.
I work on my Mac and I have not errors when I build my solution.
When I run it... I have this error : failed to find constructor for type Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxViewModelLoader and highlights base.ViewDidLoad();

#### Code :

```
public partial class MainView : MvxViewController
{
    static bool UserInterfaceIdiomIsPhone {
        get { return UIDevice.CurrentDevice.UserInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Phone; }
    }

    public MainView ()
        : base (UserInterfaceIdiomIsPhone ? "MainView_iPhone" : "MainView_iPad", null)
    {
    }

    public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning ()
    {
        // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
        base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning ();

        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
```

It's a default code, I just changed super-class (UIViewController to MvxViewController)

#### Stacktrace :

> Failed to find constructor for type Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxViewModelLoader
>     at Cirrious.CrossCore.IoC.MvxSimpleIoCContainer.IoCConstruct (System.Type type) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Cirrious.CrossCore.IoC.MvxSimpleIoCContainer+ConstructingResolver.Resolve () [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Cirrious.CrossCore.IoC.MvxSimpleIoCContainer.InternalTryResolve (System.Type type, ResolveOptions resolveOptions, System.Object& resolved) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Cirrious.CrossCore.IoC.MvxSimpleIoCContainer.InternalTryResolve (System.Type type, System.Object& resolved) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Cirrious.CrossCore.IoC.MvxSimpleIoCContainer.Resolve (System.Type t) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Cirrious.CrossCore.IoC.MvxSimpleIoCContainer.Resolve[IMvxViewModelLoader] () [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Cirrious.CrossCore.Mvx.Resolve[IMvxViewModelLoader] () [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Touch.Views.MvxViewControllerExtensionMethods.LoadViewModel (IMvxTouchView touchView) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Touch.Views.MvxViewControllerExtensionMethods+<>c_*DisplayClass1.b*_0 () [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Views.MvxViewExtensionMethods.OnViewCreate (IMvxView view, System.Func`1 viewModelLoader) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Touch.Views.MvxViewControllerExtensionMethods.OnViewCreate (IMvxTouchView touchView) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Touch.Views.MvxViewControllerAdapter.HandleViewDidLoadCalled (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at (wrapper delegate-invoke) :invoke_void_*this*__object_EventArgs (object,System.EventArgs)
>     at Cirrious.CrossCore.Core.MvxDelegateExtensionMethods.Raise (System.EventHandler eventHandler, System.Object sender) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Cirrious.CrossCore.Touch.Views.MvxEventSourceViewController.ViewDidLoad () [0x00000] in :0 
>     at TrainingCatalog.Touch.MainView.ViewDidLoad () [0x00002] in /Users/a_masteruser/Projects/DefaultCollection/_git/HapplyTrainingCatalog/TrainingCatalog.Touch/Views/MainView.cs:30 
>     at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Messaging:void_objc_msgSend (intptr,intptr)
>     at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIWindow.MakeKeyAndVisible () [0x00008] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/.pp-UIWindow.g.cs:129 
>     at TrainingCatalog.Touch.AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching (MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication app, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSDictionary options) [0x0003c] in /Users/a_masteruser/Projects/DefaultCollection/_git/HapplyTrainingCatalog/TrainingCatalog.Touch/AppDelegate.cs:21 
>     at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
>     at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x0004c] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/.pp-UIApplication.cs:38 
>     at TrainingCatalog.Touch.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00008] in /Users/a_masteruser/Projects/DefaultCollection/_git/HapplyTrainingCatalog/TrainingCatalog.Touch/Main.cs:17
>
> ### Failed to find constructor for type Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxViewModelLoader

Comment: Can you show us some code? Or some more debug output trace?

Comment: is too long to write it as a comment.

Comment: thanks - have tried to answer. If it helps, as well as adding answers, you can also edit your question to provide more info.

Comment: I put the problem paused for moment.

Answer (score 2):

From the stack trace, I'm guessing the line that is failing is: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Touch/Views/MvxViewControllerExtensionMethods.cs#L44

This is looking in IoC for a type which has been registered in setup as:

```
    protected virtual void InitializeViewModelFramework()
    {
        Mvx.RegisterType<IMvxViewModelLoader, MvxViewModelLoader>();
    }
```

(from https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross/Platform/MvxSetup.cs#L192)

Looking at `MvxViewModelLoader`, this is defined in: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross/ViewModels/MvxViewModelLoader.cs - so it should have a default `public` parameterless constructor added by the compiler...

With this in mind...

I'm guessing that maybe Xamarin is stripping out the constructor from your deployed binaries. This might be because of your linker settings - so please check that you have set the linker to link "SDK only". But if that doesn't help then this might be down to some Xamarin optimisation/feature - so you might need to .

As a simple workaround you could try overriding Setup so that you use:

```
    protected override void InitializeViewModelFramework()
    {
        Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IMvxViewModelLoader>(() => new MvxViewModelLoader>());
    }
```

However, even if this works, then I'd be worried that the linker might be stripping out other symbols in your app - so this might not be enough... you might need to chase this through with Xamarin.

Comment: I forgot to mention: 
My ViewModel has a method "public override ASYNC void Start () {...}" and I really need the keyword async... 
I say this because I just tried your solution (override InitializeViewModelFramework on Setup.cs) and MvxTrace wrote:
Problem creating viewModel of the type XXXViewModel - ... failed to find constructor for the type XXXViewModel at Cirrious.CrossCore.IoC.MvxSimpleIoCContruct(Type) in <filename unknown>

something to do with?